# Tomcat server avoid building frontend

Tags: java, git, maven, tomcat, jenkins

At the moment if I make a change on a single file (HTML,CSS,JS) and commit (using git)...

it triggers a build on jenkins.

I just feel that this is very inefficient way of working... Why is there a need to compile/build everyyyything when the changes don't even need a server restart, or to build anything.

Is there a more efficient way of escaping the build process when working on front-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just dont tell jenkins about your commit, or dont make such small commits (or dont push them).

Keep working on the frontend files and load them manually in your tomcat server. As the server doesnt even need a restart you can simply check the results.

Once you are statisfied, commit the result and push it. Jenkins may still rebuild the whole server without actually needing to do so, however, it does so only once.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why is it necessary to compile the whole project for F.End changes, I mean they are still server to client as raw text no need to compile at all... 

I don't mind them doing it, but just want to know the WHY is it necessary or can't be skipped? or controlled better.

Comment: Well, jenkins doesnt know that it doesnt have to compile the new commit. I haven't just jenkins yet, so i cant tell how to configure jenkins better.